# Who are the "among these that stand by" in Zechariah 3:7?

Tags: referent-identification, zechariah

Who are the **"among these that stand by"** in Zechariah 3:7?

> **Zechariah 3:7** Thus saith the Lord of hosts; If thou wilt walk in my
>   ways, and if thou wilt keep my charge, then thou shalt also judge my
>   house, and shalt also keep my courts, and I will give thee places to
>   walk **among these that stand by**.

Comment: These aren't small sub-questions on one topic, they're really very different questions. You need to split this up into multiple questions.

Comment: Please indicate which translation you are quoting; thanks.

Comment: Please focus your question on one of the five questions you've asked (probably the first based on the title). Then you can flag for re-open so you can add your bounty again if you'd like.

Comment: Done :-) This is already answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your first question:

The traditional Jewish approach explains that the ones "standing" refer to angels, who are described as having legs but no ability to sit.
For example, the classic commentator [Rashi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashi) [explains](https://www.sefaria.org/Zechariah.3.7?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Zechariah.3.7.1&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en):

> העומדים. שרפים ומלאכי השרת שאין להם ישיבה

"The ones that stand: this refers to the Seraphim and the ministering angels who don't posess the ability to sit."

This fits with the vision Ezekiel had, where the angels are described [as](https://www.sefaria.org/Ezekiel.1.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> וְרַגְלֵיהֶ֖ם רֶ֣גֶל יְשָׁרָ֑ה וְכַ֣ף רַגְלֵיהֶ֗ם כְּכַף֙ רֶ֣גֶל
>   עֵ֔גֶל וְנֹ֣צְצִ֔ים כְּעֵ֖ין נְחֹ֥שֶׁת קָלָֽל׃  the legs of each were
>   [fused into] a single rigid leg, and the feet of each were like a
>   single calf’s hoof; and their sparkle was like the luster of burnished
>   bronze.

The "single rigid leg" lacks the ability to bend, preventing the angels from sitting.

The angel of G-d is announcing to Joshua that if he repents, he will still merit reaching the "world to come" (which is the place associated with angels).

Comment: Thank you @Binyomin for your answer. God bless you :-)

Comment: Note that in Rashi's text, the word "by" is not present. They are not those who stand "by" but just those who "stand". This would then be a feature of all angels in his mind, that they are "standers", not just that they collocated. I don't know what version it is that was supplied in the question (though I asked for the identification per site rules) but whatever version it is, it has supplied "by" and if Rashi is correct, that would be presumptuous. Uncertainty on the text compromises my ability to answer the next question.