# What are the benefits of "walking among these that stand by" in Zechariah 3:7?

Tags: prophecy, hebrew-bible, nt-use-of-hebrew-bible, zechariah, typology

What are the benefits of **"walking among these that stand by"** in

> **Zechariah 3:7** King James Version (KJV) 7 Thus saith the Lord of hosts; If thou wilt walk in my ways, and if thou wilt keep my charge,
>   then thou shalt also judge my house, and shalt also keep my courts,
>   and **I will give thee places to walk among these that stand by.**

?

1. What are the places? What does this mean?
2. What does "walking among" mean?
3. What are the benefits of "walking among these that stand by"?

The **"these that stand by"** [seem to be angels](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/48160/who-are-the-among-these-that-stand-by-in-zechariah-37)

**Note:** *The intention is to understand what this kind of ministry is and how it will look like in practical living*

@those_who_closed_the_earlier_question I am looking for a comprehensive answer hence the three questions

Comment: I think they did not understand that the questions were intended to understand one thing: **"to understand the ministry of the priest under the new covenant if it is typified by the ministry of Joshua".** I am sad that a couple of people who does a superficial reading can come and arbitrarily close a question. This site is going to be pretty useless to anyone who wants to learn a concept comprehensively if closing questions are done on the basis of "mere technicality".  I wonder if there is a way to appeal to higher authorities if they come and to do it again to this question.

Comment: Also being a nonnative English speaker I find it difficult to phrase the question comprehensively so I split it to a no. of questions. Maybe I should learn to ask the questions in a better way. Or be able to talk with those who close the question to explain the situation. Maybe there was a way to edit the question and appeal again?

Comment: [The previous question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/48160/who-are-the-among-these-that-stand-by-in-zechariah-37) was closed by a Moderator and the reason given was that you asked five questions all at once. I notice that you have now edited and that there are four requests (at the moment) for the question to be re-opened. The above question has three queries but they are so closely regarding one feature that I doubt anyone would find that to be a problem, myself.

Comment: Ok, thank you :-)

Comment: I think the question is quite OK in its current form.

Comment: Thank you @Dottard :-)

Answer (score 2):

**What are the benefits of “walking among these that stand by” in Zechariah 3:7?**

Zechariah 3:1-7(ASV)

> 1 And he showed me Joshua the high priest standing before the angel of
>   Jehovah, and [a]Satan standing at his right hand to be his adversary.
>   2 And Jehovah said unto Satan, Jehovah rebuke thee, O Satan; yea,
>   Jehovah that hath chosen Jerusalem rebuke thee: is not this a brand
>   plucked out of the fire? 3 Now Joshua was clothed with filthy
>   garments, and was standing before the angel.
>
> 4 And he answered and spake unto those that stood before him, saying,
>   Take the filthy garments from off him. And unto him he said, Behold, I
>   have caused thine iniquity to pass from thee, and I will clothe thee
>   with rich apparel. 5 And I said, Let them set a clean [b]mitre upon
>   his head. So they set a clean [c]mitre upon his head, and clothed him
>   with garments; and the angel of Jehovah was standing by.
>
> 6 And the angel of Jehovah protested unto Joshua, saying, 7 **Thus saith
>   Jehovah of hosts: If thou wilt walk in my ways, and if thou wilt keep
>   my charge, then thou also shalt judge my house, and shalt also keep my
>   courts, and I will give thee a place of access among these that stand
>   by.**

**"Those that stand by".** Are the angels of God,(Vs 1,4), the angels have access to God in heaven. Likewise, Joshua as high priest for the Israelites would act as an intermediary and approach God directly on behalf of the people of Israel.

Also as high priest, Joshua alone has the privilege of entering into the Most Holy Place in the temple in Jerusalem. This he will do once a year on the Day of Atonement, to make atonement for himself, his household and the whole assembly of Israel.

Leviticus 16:17 (NIV)

> 17 No one is to be in the tent of meeting from the time Aaron goes in
>   to make atonement in the **Most Holy Place** until he comes out, having
>   made atonement for himself, his household and the whole community of
>   Israel.

Leviticus 16 [Full Chapter] NASB 16:1-4

[ Law of Atonement ]

> Now the Lord spoke to Moses after the death of the two sons of Aaron,
>   when they had approached the presence of the Lord and died. The Lord
>   said to Moses: “Tell your brother Aaron that he shall not enter at any
>   time into the holy place inside the veil, before the mercy seat which
>   is on the ark, or he will die; for I will appear in the cloud over the
>   mercy seat. Aaron shall enter the holy place with this: with a bull
>   for a sin offering and a ram for a burnt offering. ...

Answer (score -2):

The speaker identifies himself as the Lord of [heaven's] armies aka Michael the mighty ruler aka the Messiah/Christ and the pre-incarnate Jesus. If I am wrong on that point then my answer will require some tweaking to Michael being associated with the Angel of the LORD but not the Angel of the LORD. But to keep things simple I'll assume they are all the same person.

The Angel of the LORD suggests there will come a day when the saints would assemble for a battle with the angelic army.

In the epistle of Jude, Jude cites the scrolls of Enoch:

> [Jde 1:14 NASB] (14) It was also about these men that Enoch, in the seventh generation from Adam, prophesied, saying, "Behold, the Lord came with many thousands of His holy ones,
>
> [Enoch 1:](https://reluctant-messenger.com/book_of_enoch.htm)
>   9 And behold! He cometh with ten thousands of His holy ones
>   To execute judgement upon all,
>   And to destroy all the ungodly:
>
> And to convict all flesh
>   Of all the works of their ungodliness which they have ungodly committed,
>   And of all the hard things which ungodly sinners have spoken against Him.

There is no other canonical indication that it was Enoch that made this prediction. Instead we see it on the lips of Moses:

> [Deu 33:1-3 NASB] (1) Now this is **the blessing with which Moses the man of God blessed the sons of Israel** before his death. (2) He said, "The LORD came from Sinai, And dawned on them from Seir; He shone forth from Mount Paran, And **He came from the midst of ten thousand holy ones**; At His right hand there was flashing lightning for them. (3) "Indeed, He loves the people; **All Your holy ones are in Your hand, And they followed in Your steps**; Everyone receives of Your words.

In at least this version of the LXX, "holy ones" becomes "Cades", a place named "holiness" and it is the angels who are with him:

> Deuteronomy 33:1-3
>   LXX2012(i) 1 And this [is] the blessing with which Moses the man of God blessed the children of Israel before his death. 2 And he said, The Lord is come from Sina, and has appeared from Seir to us, and has hasted out of the mount of Pharan, **with the ten thousands of Cades; on his right hand [were] his angels with him.** 3 And he spared his people, and **all his sanctified ones [are] under your hands; and they are under you;** and he received of his words

But in addition, all his "holy ones" are "under your hands" and "they are under you", perhaps word that can refer to being soldiers along with the angels.

Many undertake to determine the timing of "the rapture" but fail to consider the *prophetic origin* of the idea, which is what I take this passage, in conjunction with Zechariah 3:7, to be. See also:

> [1Ki 22:19 NASB] (19) Micaiah said, "Therefore, hear the word of the LORD. I saw the LORD sitting on His throne, **and all the host of heaven standing by Him on His right and on His left.**

and

> [Mat 16:27 NASB] (27) "For the Son of Man is going to come in the glory of His Father with His angels, and WILL THEN REPAY EVERY MAN ACCORDING TO HIS DEEDS.

and

> [Mat 25:31-34, 46 NASB] (31) "But when the Son of Man comes in His glory, **and all the angels with Him**, then He will sit on His glorious throne. (32) "All the nations will be gathered before Him; and He will separate them from one another, as the shepherd separates the sheep from the goats; (33) and He will put the sheep on His right, and the goats on the left. (34) "Then **the King will say to those on His right, 'Come, you who are blessed of My Father, inherit the kingdom** prepared for you from the foundation of the world. ... (46) "These will go away into eternal punishment, **but the righteous into eternal life**."

These tens of thousands of saints are also the identity of the 144,000 (12,000 from each of 12 tribes) who are his first fruits:

> [Rev 14:1, 3 NASB] (1) Then I looked, and behold, **the Lamb was standing on Mount Zion, and with Him one hundred and forty-four thousand**, having His name and the name of His Father written on their foreheads. ... (3) And they sang a new song before the throne and before the four living creatures and the elders; and no one could learn the song except the one hundred and forty-four thousand who had been purchased from the earth.

See also:

> [Rev 19:11-16 KJV] (11) And I saw heaven opened, and behold a white horse; and he that sat upon him was called Faithful and True, and in righteousness he doth judge and make war. (12)  His eyes were as a flame of fire, and on his head were many crowns; and he had a name written, that no man knew, but he himself. (13) And he was clothed with a vesture dipped in blood: and his name is called The Word of God. **(14) And the armies which were in heaven followed him upon white horses, clothed in fine linen, white and clean. (15) And out of his mouth goeth a sharp sword, that with it he should smite the nations: and he shall rule them with a rod of iron: and he treadeth the winepress of the fierceness and wrath of Almighty God.** (16) And he hath on his vesture and on his thigh a name written, KING OF KINGS, AND LORD OF LORDS.

It is to this that Jesus refers in his promise:

> [Rev 3:4 NLT] (4) "Yet there are some in the church in Sardis who have not soiled their clothes with evil. They will walk with me in white, for they are worthy.

In contrast to:

> [Jer 21:5 NLT] (5) **I myself will fight against you** with a strong hand and a powerful arm, for I am very angry. You have made me furious!

### SUMMARY

So to summarize, Zechariah seems to be picking up on Enoch's prophecy on the lips of Moses that the worthy will one day join ranks with the Messiah and his angels, a theme somewhat ubiquitous in the NT.